# how to hide horizontal lines from the table without hiding vertical lines (Material-ui)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I need to hide the horizontal lines at the below table along with the timeslots.
I've tried to set the `visibility` of the `td` elements to `hidden` but this hides the vertical lines too.
Any idea how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to override the `border-bottom` style of MUI `TableCell` components.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  row: {
    "& > td": {
      borderBottom: 'none'
    }
  }
});
```

```js
{rows.map((row) => (
  <TableRow key={row.name} className={classes.row}>
    {/* your TabelCell components */}
  </TableRow>
))}
```

It's not entirely clear to me what you want to accomplish with the time column and that would require actual code to look at.